# For s/w made in VB.net, does the another computer need a .NET Framework?

Tags: vb.net

A software created using VB.net,can this s/w be installed and run directly on another computer or that computer need a .NET Framework installed?

Comment: Yes, the Framework should be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the .NET framework (runtime, not SDK) installed on the computer.

However, this is a standard part of Windows and has been for years.  Different versions of Windows come with different versions of .NET as standard.  From memory these are:

- XP SP2 will have .NET 2
- Vista has .NET 3.0
- Win7 has .NET 3.5

However, Windows Update will upgrade these by default, so realistically it's reasonably to assume it will exist on most machines.

Answer (score 1):

The machine needs the .Net Framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

If it's written in VB.NET, then it is managed code and is compiled to a .NET assembly.  In order to run a managed .NET assembly, you must have the .NET framework installed.  So, to answer your question, yes, it must be installed on any machine that will run your VB.NET application.  If you needed to make an application that could run without the framework, using Visual Studio, you would need to write unmanaged code in C++.